# How to share object between blueprint in Flask

Tags: flask

I have two blueprints, such as `auth` and `sprints`, the structure is as follows:

```
auth
    __init__.py
    views.py
    forms.py
sprints
    __init__.py
    views.py
    forms.py
```

I want to share `api` object after login successfully

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            jira_url = app.config["JIRA_URL"]
            app_id = app.config["JIRA_APPID"]
            api = GreenHopper(options={"server": jira_url, "appid": 37},
                              basic_auth=(form.username.data, form.password.data))
            g.api = api
        except JIRAError:
            api = None
        ...
        ...
        return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('scrumworks.index'))
    return render_template('auth/login.html', form=form)
```

On the `sprints` blueprint, I want to get the `api` object like codes below:

```
@scrumworks.route("/sprints")
@login_required
def show_sprints():
    if current_user.admin:
        sprints = g.api.sprints(37)
        return render_template("scrumworks/sprints.html")
    else:
      flash("Only admin users can access this page")
       return redirect(url_for(".index"))
```

When the codes run, it will complain **AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'api'**.

It seems the life cycle of `g` is per request, not global, so I can't store `api` in `g`

Another choice is `session`, but the `api` object cannot be serializable, so it can't be stored in `session`, what should I do next?

Any ideas? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `g` object is only available between requests.

The quick and dirty way to solve this, is to add your `api` object into the global space where the Flask `app` is defined and then importing the `api` object from there.

Keep in mind that with multiple servers and concurrency, this object can get out of sync fairly quickly and should remain stateless.

See [this projec](https://github.com/daeilkim/refinery/tree/master/refinery/refinery)t on github for an example

The preferred solution for this is to use a database that fits the needs of your object. Redis, MongoDB and PostgreSQL are some of the more common ones.